# Visual Studio 2012 ASP.NET bundling fails part way through

Tags: asp.net, bundle, visual-studio-2012, minify, asp.net-optimization

I'm trying to setup VS 2012's new bundling functionality (via the Microsoft.Web.Optimization package - read more [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/VisualStudio2012RCIsReleasedTheBigWebRollup.aspx)) and for the most part, everything is working alright.  The problem is that the processing just gives up after ~15000 characters.

When I build and run the page, I get a bunch of failures because the JavaScript files that have been loaded are truncated halfway through a line in the middle of a function...

Has anyone else experienced this or does anyone have any insight into how resolve this issue?

#### --UPDATE--

I originally encountered this error using `foo.AddDirectory("~/scripts/", "*.js")`.  Using `foo.AddFile("~/scripts/bar.js")` only results in the javascript errors when I include any jquery plugins.  No errors are being thrown on the server.

#### --UPDATE2--

The problem was a result of the Web Optimization library not being up to date.  I highly suggest that anyone attempting to use this retrieve the library via NuGet command line: `Install-Package -IncludePrerelease Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization`.  There are various versions of documentation and examples on the web, but the most current can be found using the above method and the most current documentation is that found in the answer below.

Comment: You'll need to narrow this down quite a bit. You're not the first to use this functionality, but you're the first I've heard of having this problem. It's unlikely to be such a generic problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a small repro?  My guess is that maybe there's an issue with the javascript files that are in the bundle.

Its also possible the minifier is choking on something and/or incorrectly minifying them.

If you are using the Scripts.Render helper, have you tried running with debug = true to make sure that everything works correctly with no bundling or minification?

Here's also the latest documentation which might be helpful: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification

Comment: I'm not using MVC, just a web form site.  I've tried adding the scripts via `Scripts.Render`, but even after importing the web.optimization namespace in the ASPX file the page throws an error.

Comment: I suspect you're correct about the minifier.  The issue is, I was using Chirpy in 2010 which worked fine -- so I wonder if I can specify an alternative minification scheme.

Comment: You can implement your own IBundleTransform and plug in whichever minifier you want, you just need to register your bundles slightly differently using the base Bundle class and pass in your transform instance.